# nginx + fpm rules problem; File not found or script is downloaded instead of being executed

Tags: php, nginx, vhosts

I'm refactoring a very old application and i'm stuck on Nginx configuration; All my tries ended up the PHP script being downloaded instead of executed, or ended up with "File not found"

**Directory Structure**

```
public
│
└─── front
│   │   index.php
│   │   
│   │
│   └─── web_www.example.com
│       │   index.php
│       │   style.css
│       │   export/
            ...
```

**The GOAL**

All URL, except static files (`.js`, `.css`...) must be routed to `public/front/index.php`

Example:

- http://www.example.com/ -> `public/front/index.php`
- http://www.example.com/index.php -> `public/front/index.php`
- https://www.example.com/mag/fr/contact.php -> `public/front/index.php`
- https://www.example.com/product-1.htm -> `public/front/index.php`
- https://www.example.com/style.css -> `serve the file`

Why some of the URL look likes as if it is a php script to be executed ?
Because it's an old app which worked this way; Now, only 1 front controller (`public/front/index.php`) is responsible of executing the code

**Base, not working vhost**

```
server {
    ...

    root /srv/app/public/front;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.app.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|ico)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }


    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /web_$http_host$uri break;
}
```

**What am I doing wrong / missing please ?**

**EDIT 1**

Adding try files to the location, like suggested by @Florentin Stemate :

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /index.php?$args $uri;
        ....
    }
```

(I switched the order and placed `$uri` at the end so we always try to go through front controller when the url contains `.php`)

Doing so is working well for all pages except:

- `https://www.example.com/product-1.htm` => now gives:

> *2 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to
>   "/web_www.test-boutique.vm/web_www.test-boutique.vm/web_www.test-boutique.vm/web_www.test-boutique.vm/web_www.test-boutique.vm/....."

Comment: try adding   `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; ` in the  `location ~ \.php$ { ` block

Comment: Thank you, the page `https://www.example.com/mag/fr/contact.php` is now working but `https://www.example.com/product-1.htm` still gives 404.

Comment: See edits for details;

Comment: what about changing `location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|ico)$` to `location ~* \.(js|css|bmp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|ico|htm|html)`

Comment: Well If i do that, the URL containing .htm will be served trying to access the file (as if it was static files); but I want all .htm URL to go through /index.php

Comment: Well then I think you can update `location ~ \.php$ {`  to `location ~ \.(php|htm)$ {`
And that should also send requests for htm files to the index.php

Comment: Thank you; the application is sending a 404 response and I thought it was nginx; that was misleading; Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `try_files` statement. Remove the `=404` so that the `/index.php$is_args$args` is the **last** parameter.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

The last parameter of `try_files` statement can be a URI, status code or a named location. Choose one! See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: I removed it; But with no effect;